# File tree view in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I was wondering how to make a file tree view in Notepad++, like other editors have, where I could open a file by clicking on it?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You can add it from the notepad++ toolbar Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager.
Then select the Explorer plugin and click the Install button.

Comment: As andrenkov mentioned open up the Plugin Manager, but choose SherloXplorer instead of the Explorer plugin, if you don't want a buggy and orphaned project, but an explorer which is as close to the real windows explorer as possible.

Comment: Same here. I used Explorer before, but that dog don't hunt.

Comment: I attempted SherlXplorer in Windows 8.1 (with .net 2.0 enabled) and it is a Notepad++ xploder! Error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: SherloXplorer is in fact the plugin that's not maintained anymore, and it has many shortcomings e.g. it doesn't remember the last open location on restart.

Comment: I installed SherloXplorer but had many errors on windows 8.1 asus t100. installed explorer and works fine with no error

Comment: I'm afraid I've had very negative experiences with SherloXplorer on my Windows 7 box - lots of object reference not found errors, rendering errors on the tree view, no history, sometimes not showing files within a folder

Comment: There's alos LightExplorer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/LightExplorer/ A bit simpler, but does the job, as well.

Comment: "Light Explorer" worked for me. "SherloXplorer" failed I think because it now requires .net. "Explorer" just failed to open with no indication of why.

Comment: Interestingly odd behavior (and somewhat annoying)  in SherloExplorer - when you double-click a file, it doesn't open in Notepad++, but in the O/S default program for that file type, which in my case was Dreamweaver.  After all, when I double-click a file in Dreamweaver, it expectedly opens in Dreamweaver no matter what the default program is.

Comment: on first glance: both SherloXplorer and Explorer use 2 windows (one that shows tree view _with folders only_ (no files), the other window with current folder's contents (sub-folders and files)) ... ... however, LightExplorer has everything in one window .... I am sure there are other comparison parameters ... but two windows is difficult to use ...

Answer (score 133):

**Tree like structure in Notepad++ without plugin**

Download Notepad++ 6.8.8 & then follow step below :

Notepad++ -> View-> Project-> choose **Panel 1** OR **Panel 2** OR **Panel 3** ->

It will create a sub part **Wokspace** on the left side -> Right click on Workspace & click **Add Project** -> Again right click on Project which is created recently -> And click on **Add Files From Directory**.

This is it. Enjoy

Comment: Seconded. This is exactly what's needed. No plugins neccessary.

Comment: Please be aware of adding root project directory, which contains tons of `node_modules`. Consider using **Folder as Workspace**, suggested by @Antti29 instead (if you can have appropriate Nodepad++ version) - it looks works fine with directories, containing `node_modules`, `bower_components` etc.

Comment: Not so good if you want to be able to browse outside the root of a single project.  In my case, I tend to have about a dozen projects on the go at once, so this method doesn't work for me.  I use LightExplorer.

Answer (score 122):

As of [Notepad++ 6.9](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.9-released.html), the new **Folder as Workspace** feature can be used.

> Folder as Workspace opens your folder(s) in a panel so you can browse folder(s) and open any file in Notepad++. Every changement in the folder(s) from outside will be synchronized in the panel. Usage: Simply drop 1 (or more) folder(s) in Notepad++.

[image: Folder as Workspace]

This feature has the advantage of not showing your entire file system when just the working directory is needed. It also means you don't need plugins for it to work.

Comment: I couldn't get the drag and drop to work but, Folder as Workspace is pretty sweet.

Comment: yes, very nice function!  Notepad++ -> File-> Open Folder as Workspace-> select folder  !  enjoy it.

Answer (score 17):

open notepad++, then drag and drop the folder you want to open as tree view.

**OR**

File ->open folder as workspace , select the file you want.

Comment: file ->open folder as workspace , select the file you want.

Answer (score 14):

If you want treeview like explorer, you can go with [LightExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/LightExplorer/LightExplorer%202.0%20UNICODE/)

[image: Light Explorer in Notepad++]

Download dll from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/LightExplorer/LightExplorer%202.0%20UNICODE/) and paste it inside plugins folder in notepad++ installed directory. Restart notepad++ and then in menubar goto ***Plugins ->Light Explorer -> Light Explorer***

Comment: This is the best answer, in my view... except that the plugin is not fully compatible with the latest version of Notepad++.  It still works, but it doesn't remember your location or favourites between sessions, and the 'synchronise with current file' feature doesn't work.  Hopefully this will be fixed at some point, but even without these features it is still my preferred method for accessing files (much better than the Explorer plugin, where files are listed in a separate panel to the folder tree).

Answer (score 3):

step-1) On Notepad++ Toolbar:

*Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Available .
Then select the Explorer. And click Install.*

(Note: As in above comments some people like SherloXplorer. Pls, note that this requires .Net v2 )

step-2) Again on Notepad++ Toolbar:

*Explorer->Explorer*

Now you can view files with tree view.

**Update:**
After adding Explorer, right click to edit a file in Notepad++ may stop working. To make it work again, restart Notepad++ afresh.

Answer (score -7):

**You can also use you own computer built-in functions:**

- Create a file, write this on it:

```
tree /a /f >tree.txt
```

- Save the file as `any_name_you_want.BAT`
- Launch it, it will create a file named `tree.txt` that contains you directory TREE.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Notepad++. This only creates a `.txt` file with an ASCII representation of your directory structure.