# Project files for Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I love Notepad++. It does everything I need it to do. I don't need a fancy IDE, I do compiling with makefiles from the command line, and the projects I work on aren't insanely huge, they have just grown beyond being small. This image describes my problem pretty well:

[image]

Is there any plugin for Notepad++ that allows you to open your project at once using a simple project file? It should provide some sort of tree view browsing of your project with **only** the files you added to the project (so no *.pyc's and stuff), and not do a whole lot more.

---

If it turns out to be impossible to add this to Notepad++ then I'm willing to actually try out a different editor that supports this but isn't a complete, heavy IDE. So answers suggesting a different but similar editor are also welcome.

Comment: Maybe it's time to move beyond Npp. For Python, check out http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I removed the python tag you added. This question is not necessarily   related to python projects.

Comment: Well, check out SharpDevelop then.  Trying to bolt on plugins to Notepad++ is the wrong approach, IMO.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Komodo edit looks nice, I might give it a shot.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I'm sorry, just the screenshots make me shudder. Besides, I am doing nothing anything .NET (C#, VB). Mostly C, C++, Python, Javascript and PHP.

Comment: I _love_ Npp as a non-suck replacement for Notepad.exe, but there comes a time to use a different tool for the job.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/nppProjectViewer-Download-129376.html but like others Stated already maybe its Time to switch to an IDE

Comment: "(so no *.pyc's and stuff)" -- where's the feature to exclude them from Notepad++ project?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No need for plugin. And NPP does this good and more. So no need to go to other editor.

Go to *View* → *Project* → *Project Panel n*

See more details [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Project_Management)

Comment: Broken link :( I suppose the answer by user2961380 suggests the same NPP feature, but the link is right ;)

Comment: at the same time its worse for a node project. as soon as you add node project folder , it starts opening all sub directories too. which includes node_modues too. It can have more 50 sub-directories with huge number of files. It attempts to expand them all by default in tree view. Its never ending

Answer (score 11):

Project Management/workspace

[image: project/workspace notepad]
Click `View` -> `Project` -> `Project Panel n`

where **n** is **1**, **2** or **3**.
Each panel for each workspace.

Comment: Good... but needs a lot of work... DRAG-AND-DROP for sure... but also a lot of features...

Answer (score 8):

Notepad++ has a project-management tool but its not very effective. Creating and deleting files is a pain, so the only things you can do with it is opening and managing of files.

But, there is a solution aka the Explorer plugin.

[Link to the explorer plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-explorer/) (You can also find it in your plugin manager)

It is a file manager and when coupled with the in-built project-management tool it is very effective.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is really helpful

Answer (score 7):

You mean a project-management like this? http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/project-management

It is already included in Notepad++, called Workspaces. It works on the local file system only. Would be great, if it works with remote filesystems like FTP/SSH too.

Comment: Your link has broken since your post, but an archived version of the page [can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131112220615/http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/project-management).

Comment: Too bad it works with local file system files only (or mapped drives)

Answer (score 4):

As of Notepad++ 6.9 (released on 22 Feb 2016 14:11:00):

The new **Folder as Workspace** feature can be used.

> Folder as Workspace opens your folder(s) in a panel so you can browse folder(s) and open any file in Notepad++. Every changement in the folder(s) from outside will be synchronized in the panel. Usage: Simply drop 1 (or more) folder(s) in Notepad++.

You can use:
File -> Open Folder as Workspace , select the folder you want.
[image]

or open Notepad++, then drag and drop the folder you want to open as tree view.

[image]

This feature has the advantage of not showing your entire file system when just the working directory is needed.
It also means you don't need plugins for it to work.

---

originally:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35767074/935330
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037872/935330